# bind9 named-checkzone failing with SOA record not at top of zone

Tags: bind9

I set up bind9 perfectly a year ago but neglected to document exactly what I done, and now something has changed and I am struggling to fix it. The problem manifested itself first from the DHCP clients which are now unable to resolve the DHCP/NS host on the LAN.

Checking my bind config with `named-checkzone` gives an error:

```
adam@gondolin:~$ sudo named-checkzone 192.168.0 /var/cache/bind/db.192.168.0
/var/cache/bind/db.192.168.0:2: SOA record not at top of zone (0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.192.168.0)
zone 192.168.0/IN: loading from master file /var/cache/bind/db.192.168.0 failed: not at top of zone
zone 192.168.0/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

Of course `named` doesn't load the zones either.

This is the zone file:

```
adam@gondolin:~$ sudo cat /var/cache/bind/db.192.168.0
$TTL 86400
0.168.192.in-addr.arpa  IN SOA  localdomain. root.localdomain. (
                                1123       ; serial
                                604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                                86400      ; retry (1 day)
                                2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                                )
                        NS      gondolin.localdomain.
$ORIGIN 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
adam@gondolin:~$
```

and my only other zone file gives the same result:

```
adam@gondolin:~$ sudo cat /var/cache/bind/db.localdomain
$TTL 86400
localdomain             IN SOA  localdomain. root.localdomain. (
                                1650       ; serial
                                604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                                86400      ; retry (1 day)
                                2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                                )
                        NS      gondolin.localdomain.
$ORIGIN localdomain.
adam@gondolin:~$
```

This is the bind config:

```
adam@gondolin:~$ cat /etc/bind/named.conf.options
acl goodclients {
    localhost;
    localnets;
};
options {
    listen-on {
        192.168.0.3;
        127.0.0.1;
    };
    listen-on-v6 {
        fe80::2a37:37ff:fe03:4225/64;
        ::1;
        #any;
    };
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    forwarders {
           208.67.220.220;
           208.67.222.222;
    };
    allow-query {
           goodclients;
    };
    allow-recursion {
           goodclients;
    };
    allow-transfer {
           goodclients;
    };
    dnssec-enable no;
    #dnssec-validation auto;
    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
};
adam@gondolin:~$
```

and the zones:

```
adam@gondolin:~$ cat /etc/bind/named.conf.local
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

include "/etc/bind/rndc.key";

zone "localdomain" {
    type master;
    notify no;
    file "/var/cache/bind/db.localdomain";
    allow-update {
        key "rndc-key";
    };
};

zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    notify no;
    file "/var/cache/bind/db.192.168.0";
    allow-update {
        key "rndc-key";
    };
};
adam@gondolin:~$
```

I'm not quite sure what other config is relevant here so I'm going to show everything I can think of.

```
adam@gondolin:~$ cat /etc/hostname
gondolin

adam@gondolin:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain gondolin
127.0.1.1   gondolin
192.168.0.3     gondolin.localdomain gondolin

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

`resolv.conf` could be a worry:

```
adam@gondolin:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 192.168.0.3
domain localdomain
search localdomain
adam@gondolin:~$
```

The `systemd-resolve` msg is irrelevant I assume, but doing a status shows this:

```
adam@gondolin:~$ sudo systemd-resolve --status
Failed to get global data: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.
```

Running a simple look-up on the host:

```
adam@gondolin:~$ dig gondolin

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.9-Ubuntu <<>> gondolin
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 58942
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 083d35c6e1daa489584481225d74b44000978776cbc340e9 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gondolin.          IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           3600    IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2019090800 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.3#53(192.168.0.3)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 08 08:56:48 BST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 140

adam@gondolin:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

With this zone configuration:

```
zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
type master;
notify no;
file "/var/cache/bind/db.192.168.0";
```

and the beginning of the zone file like this:

```
$TTL 86400
0.168.192.in-addr.arpa  IN SOA  localdomain. root.localdomain. (
```

the SOA record is actually referring to a zone named `0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.` which is obviously not right.

Why is that, you might ask?

**Because you are missing a single full stop.**

In the zone file, any domain name that does not end with a full stop (`.`) will get the zone's `$ORIGIN` appended to it automatically. If you haven't explicitly specified the `$ORIGIN`, it's the name of the zone from the `zone` configuration statement... but in the configuration statement, the full stop at the end is assumed. In the zone file, it must be explicitly specified when needed.

Once you realize this, the error message should make sense: BIND expects to see a SOA record that points to the same domain name as the `zone` configuration line.

The first line of the SOA record should be like this (if you don't use the `@`):

```
0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN SOA  localdomain. root.localdomain. (
```

The full stop at the end of 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa`.` is very important here.

Your `localdomain` zone has the same problem. It should be:

```
localdomain.             IN SOA  localdomain. root.localdomain. (
```

Answer (score 0):

Among loads of different webpages up there on this subject, I finally found this one which explained what and why as well as just giving a solution:

ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in/LDP/en/DNS-HOWTO/DNS-HOWTO-5.html

My error in the config above was in the zone files, where I needed to declare the nameserver in the nameserver properly - the config above has too much unnecessary stuff. This one worked, or at least it satisfies `named-checkzone`:

```
$TTL 3D
@                       IN SOA  gondolin.localdomain. root.gondolin.localdomain. (
                                201909091  ; serial
                                8H         ; refresh (8 hours)
                                2H         ; retry (2 hours)
                                4W         ; expire (4 weeks)
                                1D         ; minimum (1 day)
                                )
                        NS      gondolin
gondolin                A       192.168.0.3
```